# Hyper-V Windows VM's with the same speed and convenience as WSL?

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, windows-sandbox

WSL2 VM's start in seconds and are persistent. Windows Sandboxes are not persistent and setting up a Hyper-V VM's is a bit tricky and takes a bit of time to define - compared to the convenience of the "Instant On" nature of WSL2 (I just install the services, pick a Linux flavour and it's done, *and* future startups of WSL take about 1 second to start, which is incredibly fast - I would like to see something similarly convenient and fast for Windows). Remember that WSL2 is a Hyper-V VM, I used to believe that it was not, because Microsoft have done a lot to make things super-transparent, but it *absolutely* is a Hyper-V VM, with the only real difference being that it has access to the Linux kernel services now built into Windows; at the end of the day, WSL2 instances are Hyper-V VMs, and so I'm curious: shouldn't it be natural and useful to see the same level of convenience offered for Windows Hyper-V VMs as for Linux ones?
of convenience offered to Windows VM's as for
Is there a way to use Sandboxes but to make them persistent, like WSL2 instances (I'm guessing not, as I suspect that Microsoft made these non-persistent due to licensing implications)?

Does anyone have the PowerShell Hyper-V knowledge such that, if I have installed the Hyper-V service, I can run a single PowerShell script that will configure the required Hyper-V settings, then setup a Windows 10 Desktop, or  Windows Server or Windows Server Core or Windows Server Nano environment in a completely hands off way? I point the PowerShell script at a Windows ISO it is a complete, fully automated deployment (I just want to a mostly vanilla install of the OS without any special settings), and also sets a shortcut to run open that new VM instance on my Start Menu or Desktop (i.e. the same convenience and simplicity offered via WSL2). Are there maybe projects that do this on GitHub; I'd appreciate knowing if so?

Could Docker help with this in any way (possible not, as containers are more intended to run a set of service like web server functionality; we can create persistent pockets that reside outside of the container but can we get a setup similar to a Sandbox, or more-than-a-Sandbox, with the ultimate convenience of WSL2 but instead for Windows)?

Comment: Strictly speaking, WSL2 isn't a Hyper-V VM, since it can be enabled on Home editions of compatible versions of Windows. To that end neither is Windows Sandbox. Windows Sandbox wasn't designed to be persistent. Windows Sandbox was designed to have a secure enclave to run unknown software. There are third-party products like Sandboxie which provide that persistent state. However, Windows Sandbox and Sandboxie serve entirely different purposes. If you want something that is persistent, then a Docker container might be the solution, but you would have to run the service all the time.

Comment: According to the documentation provided by Microsoft, it's a managed VM, that requires `Virtual Machine Platform` in order to function.  `Virtual Machine Platform` and `Hyper-V` are two very different features.  Docker for instance also requires `Virtual Machine Platform` and Docker while using hardware virtualization also is not a Hyper-V VM.  One of the reasons WSL2 is so quick to boot up is that it's likely already in a suspended state, unless you specifically run a command, to shut down the manged VM after you close the WSL window.

Comment: That's why I said that it requires Hyper-V (as that is the foundation of WSL). Indeed, you *must* enable Hyper-V services for WSL to function, and this means that other hypervisors (VMware or VirtualBox) become kind of broken while WSL is enabled. I believe there are some workarounds, but they seem quite tricky. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58031941/how-to-get-oracle-vm-virtualbox-6-0-and-wsl-working-at-the-same-time#58478688.
My question is about similar levels of convenience for Windows VMs as WSL VMs.

Comment: Your link is outdated and does not apply to current versions of Windows that support WSL2.  The current version of VirtualBox fully supports being installed on a system with Hyper-V being enabled.  Of course, by doing so you will see a huge performance penalty. What I was going to say is in my experience my Windows Sandbox is initialized nearly instantaneously.

Comment: Hyper-V global settings can be managed by a script. VMs should be copied from saved copies, rather than created.

Comment: ok, good to point out that the above link is redundant; the state of play for WSL changed a lot from WSL to WSL2 and presumably will change a lot again for WSL3 (expected to have full GUI support) when that is released (it might be in Windows 11 in fact). I agree, Windows Sandboxes initialise very quickly, similar to WSL. But the persistence offered by WSL2 is missing, hence my related question in the OP on whether there might be projects that people have built fully automated ways to deploy vanilla VM, optimised to start nearly quickly as Windows Sandbox?

Comment: I am not sure where people are getting that WSL3 is actually a thing, it's not, Microsoft introduced WSLg when Windows 11 was released.  There are no plans, based on the discussions I have read with Microsoft developers, to backport that feature to Windows 10. Windows 10 last feature update is 21H2, and it will not support WSLg, there is only a minimal chance of it being backported to that version. I stalk the development cycles of WSL (and any other feature that has a GitHub repository) and Windows Sandbox. If you want a persistent Windows instance, you will have to use a third-party program

Comment: Well, I could run GUI apps before this announcement, and I can also do so now, so the inference is Microsoft may build in more complete graphics and audio support. I'm unconcerned either way. Microsoft planning is for them.  https://www.zdnet.com/article/microsoft-makes-support-for-linux-gui-apps-on-windows-10-generally-available/

Comment: @YorSubs - If your Windows 10 build supports WSLg then you have an Insider Preview build installed, the only Windows 10 Insider Preview build I am aware that supports WSLg, is already expired. The article you linked to while accurate, is also outdated, all builds higher than 21363 became Windows 11. The article was written before Windows 11 was announced.

Comment: @harrymc I think that if you create once and copy many, you may be able to get around GUID's, licenses would conflict eventually if they see each other, hence why I'm very curious about scripts (possibly on GitHub) that can work out all of the details to a) configure a new VM, b) setup that new VM, c) configure that VM to have Windows Sandbox like speed, d) create a Start Menu or Desktop shortcut to start it, and 15 minutes later you have a persistent Windows instance with all the convenience of a WSL2 instance.

Comment: Windows Sandbox has some serious limitations beyond the fact it doesn't have a persistent state. It not being a persistent state has little to do with concerns of licensing.  Microsoft had no problem providing a Windows XP VM with Windows 7.  [There are third-party scripts that exist that making scripting the configuration of Windows Sandbox easier.](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-Sandbox-Utilities)

Comment: Thanks, that link looks useful for Sandbox.  However, my question isn't about Sandbox; I'm only mentioning those technologies (Sandbox and WSL2) to illustrate the point that I would like to see similar levels of automated convenience (and ideally, speed) as WSL. I think that this might be achieved by means of automated PowerShell scripts, and I am hopeful that there are some solutions out there that can build such things in a fully automated manner - I would very much like to throw up a fully configured (persistent) Windows VM, in the same way that WSL is configured, on demand.

Comment: There is Quick Gallery feature in Windows 10, which allows to configure VM templates or custom images and quickly deploy VMs. https://www.hyper-v.io/hyper-v-quick-create-vm-gallery-create-one/